# Flutter popup with an arrow

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

I have attached a photo below, I need a popup Widget like the one in the image below, I am new to and have looked into existing widgets however can't seem to find anything similar. Can someone please guide me on how I can create this?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check this package https://github.com/chinabrant/popup_menu 
if it not fit your request, you can fork and do your own.

paint triangle is here
https://github.com/chinabrant/popup_menu/blob/master/lib/triangle_painter.dart

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:popup_menu/popup_menu.dart';
import 'package:popup_menu_example/gesture_demo.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Popup Menu Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PopupMenu menu;
  GlobalKey btnKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey btnKey2 = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    menu = PopupMenu(items: [
      // MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
      // MenuItem(title: 'Home', image: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,)),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Mail',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.mail,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Power',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.power,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Setting',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'PopupMenu',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.white,
          ))
    ], onClickMenu: onClickMenu, onDismiss: onDismiss, maxColumn: 1);
  }

  void stateChanged(bool isShow) {
    print('menu is ${isShow ? 'showing' : 'closed'}');
  }

  void onClickMenu(MenuItemProvider item) {
    print('Click menu -> ${item.menuTitle}');
  }

  void onDismiss() {
    print('Menu is dismiss');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PopupMenu.context = context;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // action button
          IconButton(
           key: btnKey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            onPressed: () {
              maxColumn();
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            key: btnKey2,
            icon: Icon(Icons.memory),
            onPressed: () {
              maxColumn();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () {
                  //maxColumn();
                },
                child: MaterialButton(
                  height: 45.0,
                  //key: btnKey,
                  child: Text('Show Menu'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onGesturesDemo() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GestureDemo()),
    );
  }

  void checkState(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = new SnackBar(content: new Text('这是一个SnackBar!'));

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void maxColumn() {
    PopupMenu menu = PopupMenu(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        // lineColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        maxColumn: 3,
        items: [
          MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
          // MenuItem(
          //     title: 'Home',
          //     // textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.tealAccent),
          //     image: Icon(
          //       Icons.home,
          //       color: Colors.white,
          //     )),
          // MenuItem(
          //     title: 'Mail',
          //     image: Icon(
          //       Icons.mail,
          //       color: Colors.white,
          //     )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Power',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.power,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Setting',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'PopupMenu',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
        onClickMenu: onClickMenu,
        stateChanged: stateChanged,
        onDismiss: onDismiss);
    menu.show(widgetKey: btnKey);
  }

  //
  void customBackground() {
    PopupMenu menu = PopupMenu(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        // lineColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        // maxColumn: 2,
        items: [
          MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Home',
              // textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.tealAccent),
              image: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Mail',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.mail,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Power',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.power,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Setting',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'PopupMenu',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
        onClickMenu: onClickMenu,
        stateChanged: stateChanged,
        onDismiss: onDismiss);
    menu.show(widgetKey: btnKey2);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, 

this is just what I need, the only issue is its cutting off half of the menu, any suggestions on that?

Comment: you can post this issue to let author know your request or just fork this project and customize.

Comment: Error: Field 'menu' should be initialized because its type 'PopupMenu' doesn't allow null.

Comment: This package is deprecated. Any alternatives?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah you can try [custom_pop_up_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_pop_up_menu)